# Create an array of IDs from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

[image]

I would like to iterate an object to get an array with IDs values (like this).

[image]

```
const initialState = useMemo(()=> {
        return dataTable.filter(result => favorites.some(favorite => result.id === favorite.id))
    },[results, favorites]); <--- My an object
```

I need to create an array to add in state like this:

```
const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState<React.Key[]>(['MDJ9IbxxvDUQM', 'VbnUQpnihPSIgIXuZv','GeimqsH0TLDt4tScGw']);
```

Looks a bit confusing so please any ideas how I can create an array of IDs from an object React JS

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to iterate on an array to create another one. I'd then suggest the map() solution:

`const newArray = firstArray.map(item => item.id)`

This should return an array with your id's.